# VSTO, there is an event when i change open inspector?

Tags: c#, email, outlook, vsto, mailitem

good day

I must add a button in the ribbon bar only for few specific mailitem,
i use this attribute to change the visibility.

```
getVisible="EnableControl"
```

and i use

```
IRibbonUI  UIrib.Invalidate();
```

to update the ribbon, there is an event that run when i change focused ispector, so i can check if the button must be displaied or not

or a totally different way to do do this control?

Thanks for your support.
Best regards

Comment: Please describe your question in detail. What problem do you want to solve?

Comment: Hi Lina, I want to know if there is an event or a method to execute some code when i change the active mail window. so i will can check every time if the button must be visible or not, many thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

You could  refer to the link below: [Switch focus to Outlook active window](https://www.add-in-express.com/forum/read.php?FID=5&TID=12950)  .

If you can't solve your problem, please let me know and I can give you a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever `Application.Inspectors.NewInspector` event fires, call `IRibbonUI.Invalidate`. Outlook will invoke all button state callbacks, including the `getVisible` callback.